# Updating a deep record in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this record in MongoDb, and am using the native API:

```js
{
    "_children" : {
        "addressesR" : [
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("530eea01071bd1a53065c1a6"),
                "personId" : ObjectId("530eea01071bd1a53065c1a4"),
                "street" : "ivermey",
                "city" : "perth",
                "_children" : {
                }
            },
            {
                "_children" : {
                    "configId" : {
                        "a" : {
                            "_children" : [
                                {
                                    "b" : 10
                                },
                                {
                                    "b" : 20
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "city" : "perth",
                "configId" : ObjectId("530eea01071bd1a53065c1a3"),
                "id" : ObjectId("530eea01071bd1a53065c1a5"),
                "personId" : ObjectId("530eea01071bd1a53065c1a4"),
                "street" : "bitton"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

I need to update, in one query, that nested 'b' to 30.
I can find the record:

```
db.peopleR.find( { '_children.addressesR._children.configId.a._children.b': 20 } );
```

But I am having a hard time finding a way to update that particular value.

I am trying:

```
db.peopleR.update( { '_children.addressesR._children.configId.a._children.b': 20 }, { $set: { '_children.addressesR.$._children.configId.a.$._children.b': 30 }   }  )
```

But I am getting:

```
Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.
```

Now, considering that for other constraints I absolutely need to update *just* 'b', is there a way for me to do it? Or, is it impossible to use the $ operand twice? ( that is, I can only update the inner part of an object if it's only 1 level down?)

Comment: As at MongoDB 2.4, there is no positional operator for doing a nested match & update deeper than one level. The relevant issue to watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker is [SERVER-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot use the `$` operator to show matching at nested levels in an array. And most importantly you can only specify once.

As stated from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), is that the `$` will **only** match the **first** element found. That not **only** means if you had multiple matches for your query then only the first would be picked, it also means that **only** the **first matched** array position will be used. That means something like this would also not work:

```
{ $set: { '_children.addressesR.1._children.configId.a._children.$.b': 30 }
```

As that would erroneously match the `index` `1` value and update an item you were not expecting.

If you could possibly update the **whole** array then the following would work:

```
{ $set: {"_children.addressesR.$._children.configId.a._children": [ { b: 10}, { b: 30} ] } }
```

That is as I said, because the `index` is matching for the **first** array.

But given the structure that you have, it would seem your best option is to change that top level array to be a subdocument instead. Unless in actuality this has a reason to be an array, rather than the **two** mixed document types that it appears to be now.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a problem. The second $ should go after _children. But even after that the same error appears. So it seems you are right. I tried giving the exact array position for the second part and it worked.

```
db.peopleR.update( { '_children.addressesR._children.configId.a._children.b': 20 }, { $set: { '_children.addressesR.$._children.configId.a._children.0.b': 30 }   }  )
```

Seems you need to know atleast one of the array positions.

Edit: From mongodb documents (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

> Nested Arrays The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries
>   which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse
>   arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $
>   placeholder is a single value.